# How to compile Bulgarian in my Fedora 19 distribution?

Tags: installing, babel

I am completely new to TeX.

LaTeX is already installed in my environment:

```
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
```

Saying

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bulgarian]{babel}
```

, as indicated in another answer. Byt upon processing, an error for missing .def file is indicated:

```
$ pdflatex Elementaris.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Elementaris.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 3 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-bulgarian/bulgarian.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def)

! Package babel Error: No Cyrillic encoding definition files were found.

See the babel package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.90     lcyenc.def, lwnenc.def, ot2enc.def.}
                                             %
? q
OK, entering \batchmode
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ su -c "yum install texlive-collection-langcyrillic"
```

See [this](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/TeXLive) wiki page of Fedora.